# Tomcat connection pooling, and changing the DB

Tags: tomcat

Having a little trouble with tomcat. I have a tomcat application that is exposing a soap interface for some data that needs a soap interface. All good so far. In test everything is working fine.

When I install there is an issue. I want to change the db connection to point to the live db box. So I have edited the context.xml and reloaded the application. In fact I have shutdown and restarted tomcat, just in case.

Here is my origonal context

```
    <Context>

  <Resource name="jdbc/tclsms" auth="Container" type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
               maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="100"
               user="***" password="***" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
               url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@tcl-sms:1521:smf"
               factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory"
               />

  <!-- factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory" -->           

</Context>
```

Then I change it to this

```
<Context>

  <Resource name="jdbc/tclsms" auth="Container" type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
               maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="100"
               user="***" password="***" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
               url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.40.125.150:1521:smf"
               factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory"
               />

  <!-- factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory" -->           

</Context>
```

(Passwords and users are not *** in the real setup)

Any way after making the change and doing the reload. I get an error and in the error it is telling me that it can't resolve tcl-sms.

Is there any reason that tomcat would not be loading the new context.xml

More info
I have deployed via a war file that has the origonal context.xml. 
After deploying I have gone into the webapps folder and edited the context.

The test system is Ubuntu and the live system is Solaris (if that makes any difference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I thought I'd better post here in-case some one else runs into the same thing.

Here is what happened. After deployment tomcat created a folder in webapps. This folder was named after my app and had the META-INF and WEB-INF folders. In there I found my context.xml and happily began editing.

Yet it was still looking for the wrong db host. So what I did next was grep for that host in the tomcat dir. Nothing so I thought the file must not be defined any where other than in the war file. I was wrong. There is another context.xml for my app but I did not have read permissions so the grep failed.

Then I found this http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/context-xml-not-read-td2116658.html. It turns out there is this A pre-existing context.xml for this webapp in 
$CATALINA_BASE/conf///.xml

Edited that file and it's all working. Not sure why tomcat does this....